# Post to internal php file

Tags: php

I am working on a php script which has api. The php api file name is : api.php so to get infos the url is like this : `http://www.google.com/api.php?user=x&password=y&format=simple` everything works just fine when using url. Sometimes i need to make this query from internal server (the one hosting site.com) so it's dumb to make the request as remote. I tried `file_get_contents("api.php?user=x&password=y&format=simple") and include() also`
but it doesn't work

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: file_get_contents() .. will not run the php, you will jsut get the source code

Comment: If I spend as much time on an answer as your question then yo... time is up! Please read [ask] a question here.

Comment: try adding the domain name also , like file_get_contents("http://localhost/api.php?user=x&password=y&format=simple")

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya - my interpretation of 'everything works just fine when using url', is that Testila is aware of how to make the call in that manner, and 'i need to make this query from internal server (the one hosting site.com) so it's dumb to make the request as remote' that they wish to do this without making a remote url call.

Comment: @SamuelJackson Yes exactly you are right i am not a native english speaker so i am doing my best so you guys can understand and help . thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to include that file which is receiving `$_REQUEST` key/value pairs, you can set the values first, then include the file.

```
$_REQUEST = Array(
   'user' => 'x',
   'password' => 'y',
   'format' => 'simple'
);

include('api.php');
```

If you are using `$_POST`, you can set that array the same way, just replace `$_REQUEST` with `$_POST`

Comment: While I did not downvote, it saddens me to see the usage of `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @Xorifelse - I agree, but the author wanted to know a way to basically hack the request variables on a file while calling only locally that accepts values normally sent as `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.  Without heavy modification of the `api.php` file, and without calling the file over the web (curl, etc), this is really a cheap way to get the job done.

Comment: @Dagon Please read the answer before you comment. He has used `include` which surely runs the PHP.

Comment: @Dagon - that is true. Hence why I did not suggest that method. I can see why that was attempted as they believed simply appending the key/value pairs would pass those to the $_REQUEST array (obviously doesn't work). If they wanted to do `file_get_contents`, simply replace `include('api.php')` with `exec(file_get_contents('api.php'));`. Like i said -- hack.

Comment: @SamuelJackson You do mean `eval()` instead of `exec()` right? Secondly, you can also just set a global variable.